# stripe doesn't accept secret key

Tags: typescript, stripe-payments

I seem to be doing something wrong passing the secret key to the Stripe object.. I'm using typescript

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import Stripe from 'stripe';
    
const stripe = new Stripe("sk_test_.....", {
  apiVersion: '2020-03-02',
});
```

I'm getting a frontend error:

```
ou did not provide an API key. You need to provide your API key in the Authorization header, using Bearer
    auth (e.g. 'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_SECRET_KEY')
```

Anything obvious I'm doing wrong...

Comment: Is this how the code is actually configured, or are you using something to manage the secret key from an environment variable or other secret management? This is recommended, but is also often the source of missing secret keys.

Comment: ..no I originally had in a environment variable. But that wasn't working so now I'm just copying and pasting in the string

Comment: Since I don't expect `new Stripe(...)` itself to throw this error, can you share a more complete snippet including the actual request that triggers this? You may need to initialize stripe inside the function execution rather than once ahead of time.